# C# - Fetching property value from child class

Tags: c#, reflection

I access property value from a class object at run-time using reflection in C#.

```
    public bool GetValue(string fieldName, out object fieldValue)
    {
        // Get type of current record
        Type curentRecordType = _currentObject.GetType();
        PropertyInfo property = curentRecordType.GetProperty(fieldName);

        if (property != null)
        {
            fieldValue = property.GetValue(_currentObject, null).ToString();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            fieldValue = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I pass Property Name as parameter: fieldName to this method.
Now, I need to access a property value from the child object of above class at run-time.
Can anyone there please guide how can I access child object property value?

Comment: Do you have a problem or is there another question here?

Comment: edited my question, need a way to access child object property value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you want to be able to find objects on arbitrarily-nested child objects, you need a function that you can call recursively. This is complicated by the fact that you may have children that refer back to their parent, so you need to keep track of which objects you've seen before in your search.

```
static bool GetValue(object currentObject, string propName, out object value)
{
    // call helper function that keeps track of which objects we've seen before
    return GetValue(currentObject, propName, out value, new HashSet<object>());
}

static bool GetValue(object currentObject, string propName, out object value,
                     HashSet<object> searchedObjects)
{
    PropertyInfo propInfo = currentObject.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
    if (propInfo != null)
    {
        value = propInfo.GetValue(currentObject, null);
        return true;
    }
    // search child properties
    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo2 in currentObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {   // ignore indexed properties
        if (propInfo2.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
        {
            object newObject = propInfo2.GetValue(currentObject, null);
            if (newObject != null && searchedObjects.Add(newObject) &&
                GetValue(newObject, propName, out value, searchedObjects))
                return true;
        }
    }
    // property not found here
    value = null;
    return false;
}
```

If you know what child object your property is in you can just pass the path to it, like so:

```
public bool GetValue(string pathName, out object fieldValue) 
{ 
    object currentObject = _currentObject;
    string[] fieldNames = pathName.Split(".");

    foreach (string fieldName in fieldNames)
    {
        // Get type of current record 
        Type curentRecordType = currentObject.GetType(); 
        PropertyInfo property = curentRecordType.GetProperty(fieldName); 

        if (property != null) 
        { 
            currentObject = property.GetValue(currentObject, null).ToString(); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            fieldValue = null; 
            return false; 
        } 
    }
    fieldValue = currentObject;
    return true; 
}
```

Instead of calling it like `GetValue("foo", out val)` you would call it like `GetValue("foo.bar", out val)`.

Comment: giving the path name for each property is not possible in my case as there are hundreds of properties. Want a short and efficient way where my code can go down to child object and fetch the property value giving only the parent Object and Property name as input.

Comment: So you're saying that you have a tree of objects where each property among all the objects has a unique name, and you want to be able to find an arbitrarily nested property given only its name? (if you have foo.bar.baz.qux, you want to just pass in "qux" and have the function figure out that it's within `foo.bar.baz')

Comment: inutan: That significantly complicates things. See my revised function.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. Could you please add your previous function where passing path name for each property as parameter... might need that.

Comment: inutan: OK, I put the old way back in below the new way.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, only change I made was removing 'ToString()' in currentObject = property.GetValue(currentObject, null).ToString();

Comment: You don't have to use recursion. You could push objects on a stack and declare victory when they've all been popped off. It's a little harder to read but it runs faster.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below function. This approach worked for me.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of the property of the object by name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static object GetPropertyByName(this object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
            return value;
        }

        if (propertyName.Split('.').Length > 0)
        {
            string[] fieldNames = propertyName.Split(".");
            PropertyInfo currentProperty;
            object currentObject = obj;
            foreach (string fieldName in fieldNames)
            {
                Type curentRecordType = currentObject.GetType();
                currentProperty = curentRecordType.GetProperty(fieldName);

                if (currentProperty != null)
                {
                    var value = currentProperty.GetValue(currentObject, null);
                    if (fieldNames.Last() == fieldName)
                    {
                        return value;
                    }

                    currentObject = value;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This question then can be called as below.

```
var value = obj.GetPropertyByName("Object1.Object2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Main(){
    var containerObject = new ContainerObject();
    object propertyValue;
    object nestedPropertyValue;
    if(GetValue(containerObject, "FirstPropertyName", out propertyValue){
       bool success = GetValue(propertyValue, "NestedPropertyName", out nestedPropertyValue);
    } 

}

public bool GetValue(object currentObject, string propertyName, out object propertyValue)
{
    // Get type of current record
    var currentObjectType = currentObject.GetType();
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = currentObjectType.GetProperty(propertyName);

    propertyValue = propertyInfo != null 
                    ?  propertyInfo.GetValue(currentObject,null)
                    :  null;
    return propertyValue == null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks smartcaveman, but I do not in advance which particular property of main object will be parent for the nested property. In which case, your code snippet won't solve my problem.

Comment: You can get all the properties by using GetProperties instead of  GetProperty(name).  I could help you more if you would further specify the objective.